# Select the similar value in column from another table and use another table value in main table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table1 with has all the shops name as below:

Table 1

```
id|name
1 |wairau road
```

In my second table2, I have the following value:

Table 2

```
id|name        |customer_name
 1|wairau rd   |shelly
 2|wairau road |andy
 3|wairauroad  |ally
```

When I do a `select * from table 2`,

My expected output will be as below:

id|    name   |customer_name
    1|wairau road|shelly
    2|wairau road|andy
    3|wairau road|ally

Noticed that the name is now to sync with the name from table1. Is there a way we can do this in postgres/redshift SQL?

Comment: You really need to fix the data.  This can be quite tricky with a query.

Comment: If your `Table 2` had a foreign key to `Table 1`, then yes. Add it, and a simple join will do the trick.

Comment: @TheImpaler, unfortunately, there's no foreign key on both tables.. its just plain tables on both

Comment: Then, there's no way the database engine can **guess** the names of the shops.

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks, i guess i'll check with the supplier then to fix the data

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Although they share some ancient roots they are [very different](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html)

Answer (score 2):

As you've already heard, the solution to dirty data is cleaning it up. If you're dealing with address data like you show, address standardization is a good subject to look into on its own. It's such a common problem that there are lots of solutions and services. The best approach can depend a lot on what countries you need to support, and what your budget is.

You've already had a good suggestion of using soundex to help with this. What soundex does is translates strings into a code so that similar-sounding strings convert to the same code. This translation can be prepared in advance and stored in an index, which can make soundex comparisons very fast. On the bad side, soundex is from a hundred years ago, was meant for scoring surnames, and was set up for a version of American English. So it's not a great match for every problem. You'll find Meataphone in the same extension, it's potentially a little better, but more-or-less has the same pros and cons. That extension also has Levenshtein Distance, also called "edit distance." It counts how many changes have to be made to turn one string into another string. It's better at longer strings than very short strings. It's great! But it's also not something you can pre-calculate as you don't know what you're going to compare it to. But it's a good tool for ranking similar strings, once you've found some likely matches by some other means.

Speaking of other means, there's another excellent tool in Postgres to check out:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html

It's part of the standard package, so you would install it the same way as the instructions you got already for fuzzystringmatch. Trigrams are a world beyond the simple fuzzy string matches listed above. They've got a ton of research behind them, work well across different languages and data sets, great stuff. I finally spent some time looking at the Postgres implementation last week and it's great

```
select 'wairau rd' as address, show_trgm('wairau rd')   union all
select 'wairau rd' as address, show_trgm('wairau road') union all
select 'wairau rd' as address, show_trgm('wairauroad')
```

That spits out something like this:

```
address,show_trgm
wairau rd,"{""  r"",""  w"","" rd"","" wa"",air,""au "",ira,rau,""rd "",wai}"
wairau rd,"{""  r"",""  w"","" ro"","" wa"",""ad "",air,""au "",ira,oad,rau,roa,wai}"
wairau rd,"{""  w"","" wa"",""ad "",air,aur,ira,oad,rau,roa,uro,wai}"
```

The magic part is that Postgres then can use these chunks to make some really good comparisons and guesses with an index. Since the index is on these tiny chunks that cover the whole string, you get away from the left-anchor limitations of a standard B-tree. This provides a lot of flexibility and power, without making queries slow.

There are two ways of setting up the index, depending on the kind of comparisons you're interested in. There are some time and space trade-offs too, but that's something to check out once you're sure this tool is even a good match for you. Here are the two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX table_1_names_gin
    ON table1
    USING gin (address gin_trgm_ops);

CREATE INDEX table_1_names_gist
    ON table1
    USING gist (address gist_trgm_ops);
```

I'm calling your field "address" here as I wouldn't call a field name. Once you have indexes such as these, you can then do fast LIKE or ILIKE searches, and pattern matching searches without complex regular expression syntax. Something like this (not tested) for a starts-with search:

```
select * 
  from table2
 where address ILIKE 'wairu%'
```

or even this for a contains search:

```
select * 
  from table2
 where address ILIKE 'wairu%'
```

Or this for a similarity search:
from analytic_scan

```
select * 
  from table2
 where address %> 'wairu'
```

There's a lot more than that, but I'll stop. And, honestly, address standardization ought to be your first step no matter what. But fuzzy matching can help.

Tip: In the past, I've found that there are often good (usability/UX) reasons people put in bad or inconsistent addresses. If your database is part of a corporate application, one option is to run a report every night finding and flagging address or names that look non-standard. Fuzzy-matching can be really useful here. Then, someone can help train the people who are making mistakes to do better. Or maybe what you find out is that the UI of the system makes it easier to enter bad data than good. In which case, you can rework the app to be better and measure the change in near duplicates to measure how well you're doing.

Comment: thanks for your idea and comment! will have a look into it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use soundex (in extension fuzzystrmatch). Test in [the SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/302b9/1/0)

```
CREATE EXTENSION if not exists fuzzystrmatch;
CREATE TABLE t1 (id int, name text);
CREATE TABLE t2 (id int, name text, customer_name text);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1, 'wairau road');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (2, 'joe road');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (3, 'jerry road');
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1, 'wairau rd', 'shelly');
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2, 'wairau road', 'andy');
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (3, 'wairauroad', 'ally');
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (4, 'joe  row', 'john');
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (5, 'joe.rd', 'jack');

SELECT DISTINCT ON (t2.id) t2.id, t1.name, t2.customer_name,
                           t2.name AS data_entry_name
FROM t2
CROSS JOIN t1
ORDER BY t2.id, t1.name = t2.name DESC, difference(t1.name, t2.name) DESC, t1.name
```

The query could be quite slow if there is a lot of data. It chooses the most likely match via the ORDER BY, in this case, in order:

1. if the names are exactly the same
2. if the names are similar (1=not similar .. 4=quite similar)
3. alphabetical order of name in Table 1

You could add more rules, e.g. if the lowercase version without spaces match.

The problem with this query is that it will show the likeliest match, which could be completely wrong in the absence of a likely match. Also, it's a best guess so the query could make the wrong choices.